# Android TV SearchEditText requestFocusFromTouch() not calling SearchResultProvider

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tv, leanback

I'm trying to create an in-app search using Android Leanback's SearchFragment (`android.support.v17.leanback.app.SearchFragment`). I have successfully created the fragment and a results provider, however I would like the fragment to focus the text search box immediately. However, while calling requestFocus() or similar (requestFocusFromTouch(), requestFocus(View.FOCUS_RIGHT), etc.) causes the search box to gain focus and the on-screen-keyboard to pop up, the search functions in my SearchResultProvider do not get called.

This appears to be the case for all ways of focusing the search box, apart from pressing right with the SpeechOrbView focused.

Why are the result provider functions not being called, and how can I change the focus whilst keeping their functionality?

Comment: Did you receive any kind of error?

Comment: @KENdi nope, it just doesn't do anything